# How to clean sentences for StanfordNER

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

I want to use `StanfordNER` in python to detect named entities. How should i clean up the sentences?

for example, consider

`qry="In the UK, the class is relatively crowded with Zacc competing with Abc's Popol (market leader) and  Xyz's Abcvd."`

if i do

```
st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz') 
print st.tag(qry.split())
```

i get

```
[
    (u'In', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'UK,', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), 
    (u'class', u'O'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'relatively', u'O'), (u'crowded', u'O'), 
    (u'with', u'O'), (u'Zacc', u'PERSON'), (u'competing', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), 
    (u"Abc's", u'O'), (u'Popol', u'O'), (u'(market', u'O'), (u'leader)', u'O'), 
    (u'and', u'O'), (u"Xyz's", u'O'), (u'Abcvd.', u'O')
]
```

`

so only 1 named entities was detected. However, if i do some cleanup by replacing all special characters with spaces

`qry="In the UK the class is relatively crowded with Zacc competing with Abc s Popol  market leader and  Xyz s Abcvd"`

i get

```
[
    (u'In', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'UK', u'LOCATION'), (u'the', u'O'), 
    (u'class', u'O'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'relatively', u'O'), (u'crowded', u'O'), 
    (u'with', u'O'), (u'Zacc', u'PERSON'), (u'competing', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), 
    (u'Abc', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u's', u'O'), (u'Popol', u'PERSON'), (u'market', u'O'), 
    (u'leader', u'O'), (u'and', u'O'), (u'Xyz', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u's', u'O'), (u'Abcvd', u'PERSON')]
```

`

so clearly, this is more appropriate. Are there any general rules on how to clean up sentences for `StanfordNER`? Initially i thought that there is no cleanup required at all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Stanford Tokenizer for your purpose. 
You could use the code below.

```
from nltk.tokenize.stanford import StanfordTokenizer
token = StanfordTokenizer('stanford-ner-2014-06-16/stanford-ner.jar')
qry="In the UK, the class is relatively crowded with Zacc competing with Abc's Popol (market leader) and  Xyz's Abcvd."
tok = token.tokenize(qry)
print tok
```

You will get the tokens as you require them.

> [u'In',
>    u'the',
>    u'UK',
>    u',',
>    u'the',
>    u'class',
>    u'is',
>    u'relatively',
>    u'crowded',
>    u'with',
>    u'Zacc',
>    u'competing',
>    u'with',
>    u'Abc',
>    u"'s",
>    u'Popol',
>    u'-LRB-',
>    u'market',
>    u'leader',
>    u'-RRB-',
>    u'and',
>    u'Xyz',
>    u"'s",
>    u'Abcvd',
>    u'.']

Answer (score 2):

You should make sure that you are tokenizing the sentence -- this is the big difference between the first invocation (where you implicitly tokenize incorrectly with `qry.split()`) and the second, where you've manually tokenized (e.g., posessive `'s` as its own token). Stanford [does have a tokenizer](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/tokenizer.shtml), which is the tokenizer the NER system was trained on, though I'm not an expert on how to call it from Python. Does simply not splitting the sentence tokenize it for you?

Answer (score 1):

Please word tokenize the text before processing them. Also, do note that most annotation systems are trained from sentences so you might do sentence tokenization before word tokenization.

```
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORDTOOLSDIR=$HOME
alvas@ubi:~$ export CLASSPATH=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/stanford-ner.jar
alvas@ubi:~$ export STANFORD_MODELS=$STANFORDTOOLSDIR/stanford-ner-2015-12-09/classifiers
alvas@ubi:~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec 15 2015, 16:46:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from nltk import word_tokenize
>>> from nltk.tag import StanfordNERTagger
>>> from nltk.internals import find_jars_within_path
>>> st = StanfordNERTagger('english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz')
>>> stanford_dir = st._stanford_jar.rpartition('/')[0]
>>> stanford_jars = find_jars_within_path(stanford_dir)
>>> st._stanford_jar = ':'.join(stanford_jars)
>>> 
>>> text = "In the UK, the class is relatively crowded with Zacc competing with Abc's Popol (market leader) and  Xyz's Abcvd."
>>> text = word_tokenize(text)
>>> text
['In', 'the', 'UK', ',', 'the', 'class', 'is', 'relatively', 'crowded', 'with', 'Zacc', 'competing', 'with', 'Abc', "'s", 'Popol', '(', 'market', 'leader', ')', 'and', 'Xyz', "'s", 'Abcvd', '.']
>>> st.tag(text)
[(u'In', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'UK', u'LOCATION'), (u',', u'O'), (u'the', u'O'), (u'class', u'O'), (u'is', u'O'), (u'relatively', u'O'), (u'crowded', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), (u'Zacc', u'PERSON'), (u'competing', u'O'), (u'with', u'O'), (u'Abc', u'PERSON'), (u"'s", u'O'), (u'Popol', u'O'), (u'(', u'O'), (u'market', u'O'), (u'leader', u'O'), (u')', u'O'), (u'and', u'O'), (u'Xyz', u'ORGANIZATION'), (u"'s", u'O'), (u'Abcvd', u'O'), (u'.', u'O')]
```